# TCPDF sometimes generate php file

Tags: html, pdf, tcpdf

Let me describe the case:

I want to fill up a form in web then populate the forms data to a page then i need to download that page as PDF. I am using TCPDF.

TCPDF works in most of the time. But when there is a large html page need to convert into PDF it sometimes just give me the .php file for download. And after downloading the php file it show some special character inside the .php file.

In 80% time i get the PDF as accepted. But in 20% time i get the .php file. I google a lot about it but didn't find anything helpful.

My HTML page link is : http://app.ans4u.com/wp-content/themes/dctappv2/requre/pdf-creator/passport-form.php

You can see the plain html code in the source. In the page you will find a download button. If you click it 5times you will see 1 or 2 time its returning a php file to download.

To generate the PDF what i am using the code below:

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf.class.php');
 try
 {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF($form_orientation, 'Letter', 'fr');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->Output('form-'.$form_no.'.pdf','D');
 }
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
 }
```

Am i missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a lot of Googling and performance testing i found that TCPDF use a good percentage of ram when it process a very large complex php page. So when there are good amount of user in my website and try to generate the pdf the ram go high and became busy for a long time, so its become timeout of memory use. On that case its breakdown and return a .php file with special character.

Looks like no one faced it. But i was using a shared hosting so i faced it a lot.

Hope this information will be helpful for someone in future.